# Using a label in different locations (WinForm)

Tags: c#, label

I want to use a label under different Tabpages. So when I update one, I want the other to be updated. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Let us know what you tried.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net maybe? Too little information.

Comment: Winform, sorry.

Comment: @Emre added a possible winforms solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achive this by binding all the other label to your source lable like this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="lbl1" Content="Woohoooooo"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=lbl1,Path=Content}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=lbl1,Path=Content}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=lbl1,Path=Content}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

All label will always update their text to be the same as `lbl1`

**EDIT:**

You are using **winforms** so the above wont work for you but you can use the text Changed event in winforms to achive that. SOmething like this should do the trick (not tested i dont use winforms):

```
    //in your form constuctor you add the event like this:
    NameOfYourSourceTextBox.TextChanged += SourceTextbox_TextChanged;

    //to call this function when the text on the label changes 
    private void SourceTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as Label).text;
        //now you set all your labels to the same text and from now on you only need to channge the source alabel and all others will follow
        Label1.Text = text;
        Label2.Text = text;
        Label3.Text = text;
    }
```